# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mpirun', '-np', '2', '/usr/bin/python3.7', '-u', 'train.py']' returned non-zero exit status 134

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, subprocess, mpi

**Hello, I am using python 3.7 and running the following code :**

```
if "parent" == mpi_fork(args.num_worker+1): os.exit()
```

**where mpi_fork is**

```
def mpi_fork(n):
"""Re-launches the current script with workers
  Returns "parent" for original parent, "child" for MPI children
  (from https://github.com/garymcintire/mpi_util/)
"""
 if n<=1:
    return "child"
 if os.getenv("IN_MPI") is None:
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env.update(
      MKL_NUM_THREADS="1",
      OMP_NUM_THREADS="1",
      IN_MPI="1"
    )
    print("\n\nHello\n\n")
    print( ["mpirun", "-np", str(n), sys.executable] + sys.argv)
    subprocess.check_call(["mpirun", "-np", str(n),sys.executable] +['-u']+ sys.argv,    env=env)
    return "parent"
  else:
    global nworkers, rank
    nworkers = comm.Get_size()
    rank = comm.Get_rank()
    print('assigning the rank and nworkers', nworkers, rank)
    return "child"
```

**and I've got the following error:**

```
2020-06-24 10:00:55.817305: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created     TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6271 MB memory) -> physical   GPU (device: 0, name: Quadro P4200, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-06-24 10:00:55.858934: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 6.12G (6576128000 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.859365: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 5.51G (5918515200 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.859810: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 4.96G (5326663680 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.860166: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 4.46G (4793997312 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.860540: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 4.02G (4314597376 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.861072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 3.62G (3883137536 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.861451: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 3.25G (3494823680 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.861801: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 2.93G (3145341184 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.862153: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 2.64G (2830807040 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.862554: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 2.37G (2547726336 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.862936: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 2.13G (2292953600 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.863306: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 1.92G (2063658240 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.863665: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 1.73G (1857292544 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.864025: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 1.56G (1671563264 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.864391: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 1.40G (1504407040 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.864748: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 1.26G (1353966336 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.865104: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 1.13G (1218569728 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.865569: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 1.02G (1096712704 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.866050: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 941.32M (987041536 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.866422: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 847.18M (888337408 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.866779: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 762.47M (799503616 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.867130: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 686.22M (719553280 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.867488: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 617.60M (647598080 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.867860: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 555.84M (582838272 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.868222: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 500.25M (524554496 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.868577: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 450.23M (472099072 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.868930: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 405.21M (424889344 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.869288: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 364.69M (382400512 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.869652: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 328.22M (344160512 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-06-24 10:00:55.960490: F ./tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: out of memory

[antonio-HP-ZBook-17-G5:07714] *** Process received signal ***

[antonio-HP-ZBook-17-G5:07714] Signal: Aborted (6)

[antonio-HP-ZBook-17-G5:07714] Signal code:  (-6)

2020-06-24 10:00:55.960557: F ./tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: out of memory

[antonio-HP-ZBook-17-G5:07715] *** Process received signal ***

[antonio-HP-ZBook-17-G5:07715] Signal: Aborted (6)

[antonio-HP-ZBook-17-G5:07715] Signal code:  (-6)


Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.


mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node antonio-HP-ZBook-17-G5 exited on signal 6 (Aborted).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 460, in <module>
    if "parent" == mpi_fork(args.num_worker+1): os.exit()
  File "train.py", line 433, in mpi_fork
    subprocess.check_call(["mpirun", "-np", str(n),sys.executable] +['-u']+ sys.argv, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mpirun', '-np', '2', '/usr/bin/python3.7', '-u', 'train.py']' returned non-zero exit status 134.
```

**Can anyone help me to solve this probmlem?**

Comment: "Internal: out of memory" sounds pretty straightforward to me

Comment: So do you have any idea? And thank you for your response

Comment: When you run MPI processes, they will all try and allocate all the memory on the GPU (which I understand is the default behaviour of tensorflow). Obviously that won't work. You need to look at the memory allocation policies of tensorflow and your code and see whether mulitple processes can actually coexist on your GPU. It might be that it isn't possible. I know nothing about tensorflow. But I can read error logs and I do know that this isn't a CUDA programming related question, which is why I left you the comment when I removed the CUDA tag